# Why does React Native's .flowconfig ignores .android.js files?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I wanted to test flow in my React Native project. I ran flow and found that it had no effect on Android files. I found the below given code in .flowconfig:

```
[ignore]

# We fork some components by platform.
.*/*.web.js
.*/*.android.js
```

Why did the React Native team ignore these files? I was not able find much information about the same else where. I know that I can make edits and flow would start considering android files as well, but I am not sure if it'd be right. For example, this is what **fabergua** has commented on a issue [Flow doesn't recognize platform-specific react-native files](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/945) related to it:

> @mhollweck : React Native's default .flowconfig is set up to ignore
>   all .android.js files. You can work around this by changing
>   -.*/*[.]android.js to .*/node_modules/.*/*[.]android.js in the .flowconfig of your project.

But, should we go ahead with such workaround? Wouldn't it mess with the project when we upgrade it via **react-native-git-upgrade**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always thought that they ignore Android by default because oftentimes you would prefer Flow to consistently operate on a particular platform's modules, and iOS was the original platform for React Native. Say you try to "jump to definition" for a particular function defined in both `myFunction.ios.js` and `myFunction.android.js`. With `*.android.js` ignored, Flow will consistently jump you to the `*.ios.js` files. So if your app is primarily focused on Android, I'd switch that ignore to `*.ios.js`.

Comment: Got it. But, what if my primary focus is both i.e Android and iOS ? Also, is it Ok to change configurations set by React Native team?

Comment: It is definitely ok to change the default configurations as long as you understand what they're doing. I would try removing the `*.android.js` ignore if I were you, and see if that works for you.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Tanner

Comment: I've just tried removing the `[ignore]` of `.*/*[.]android.js` and this results in Flow producing a multitude of "Duplicate module provider" errors.

Comment: @tafty What happens if you switch it to ios? I think those errors are telling you that Flow sees multiple matches for the same module import, and doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: If it's switched to iOS it just uses the android definitions. I agree that Flow just doesn't take into account that, whilst there's two definitions, they will only be used in mutually exclusive contexts.

Answer (score 1):

`*.android.js` files are ignored by default to choose a platform arbitrarily, but there is also need to run flow in the following way:

```
[ignore]
; We fork some components by platform
.*/*[.]ios.js

...

[options]
module.file_ext=.native.js
module.file_ext=.android.js
module.file_ext=.js
```